# Accessing jobParameter on ItemProcessor on Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I'm new to spring batch and during my development I came across a scenario where I need to access a jobParameter on an ItemProcessor. I've done this on a reader (MultiresourceReader and StaxeventItemReader also with a CustomReader that I have built) and it was successful, I can retrieve jobParameter but not with ItemProcessor.

Here is my snippet.

```
<bean id="myProcessor" class="com.......MyCustomProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="myBean" ref="customBean"/>
</bean>
<bean id="customBean" class="...................MyCustomBean" scope="step">
    <property name="file" value="#{jobParameters['FILE']}/fileName.txt"/>
</bean>
```

It is producing a lazyBinding Exception. Any idea on how to retrieve the jobParameter on an item Processor?

Answer (score 3):

From what I see in your snippet, you try to access the job parameter from a customBean... Not the *ItemProcessor*!.

A regular bean in Spring DOES NOT understand the *step*-scope. The scope for a Spring bean is singleton, prototype, request or session!

If you move your

```
<property name="file" value="#{jobParameters['FILE']}/fileName.txt"/>
```

to the *ItemProcessor* it should work.

I assume you use the customBean inside the processor?  If so, then you will be able to set the value of the jobParameter inside the *ItemProcessor*.